# How can I boot back into Windows 8 after intalling Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, dell, uefi

So, I have a Dell Laptop, and I've been interested in Dual Booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu, just because Ubuntu seems interesting and I enjoy fiddling with things.

I have Ubuntu up and running, but now i can't access Windows 8. It's not even an option in the UEFI Boot configuration.

I made sure not to agree to wiping or formatting anything. The only thing I did that made me a little suspicious was create a partition that was 500 GB, the size of my hard drive.

All I would like to do is boot back into windows 8 if possible. If not, I guess i'm learning all about Ubuntu today.

Comment: try `sudo update-grub` command on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you give us the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? Please *edit* it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing coming in my mind is that you have made Ubuntu as a default option.So press F12 when booting,And in that please do make necessary settings.Or you can turn on the secure boot.